# Is there any way to embed a terminal window in TextMate?

Tags: shell, terminal, textmate

I'd like to be able to split my TextMate window in two, with the usual editor in one half of the window, and a terminal in the other half. Something similiar to [this layout](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/8373/86448854.jpg) in Notepad++ (on Windows).

I have been searching for how to do this for 2 hours and haven't found it yet.

Comment: I would like to know this as well. I've also been searching for quite some time and can't find anything